# sqlalchemy REST serialization

Tags: python, rest, xml-serialization, sqlalchemy

Reading the doc of sqlalchemy, i saw the serialization part.
I'm wondering about a possibility to use an xml serializer for matching sa models with Rest webservices like Jax-RS
There is a django extension which deal with that : [django_roa](http://bitbucket.org/david/django-roa/)
Do you know if that kind of thing has already been developped for sqlalchemy or if is it possible to do it??
Thanks

Comment: After some researches i wrote a little app to shows what i want :
http://bitbucket.org/ee_lars/resttest The code is really ugly ... The serialization is ok for classical fields (Integer, Unicode, Boolean..) but i didn't find the way to handle Foreign Keys and stuffs like that.
I think it's possible to "detect" that a field is in a particular type (from the mapper of his Model) and then putting URI of the related model as a link in the serialized resource. Anyway i have no idea on how to do that : any possibility/idea??? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its a long way till full RFC2616 compliance, but for a prototype, I do something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relation, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import desc
import web
import json

DB_PATH = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'

Base = declarative_base()

class LocalClient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'local_clients'
    __jsonexport__ = ['id', 'name', 'password']

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False) 
    password = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<LocalClient('%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.password)

urls = (
    '/a/LocalClient', 'LocalClientsController'
)

class Encoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    '''This class contains the JSON serializer function for user defined types'''
    def default(self, obj):
        '''This function uses the __jsonexport__ list of relevant attributes to serialize the objects that inherits Base'''
        if isinstance(obj, Base):
            return dict(zip(obj.__jsonexport__, [getattr(obj, v) for v in obj.__jsonexport__]))
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

class LocalClientsController:
    '''The generic RESTful Local Clients Controller'''
    def GET(self):
        '''Returns a JSON list of LocalClients'''
        engine = create_engine(DB_PATH, echo=False)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
        clis = session.query(LocalClient)
        return json.dumps([c for c in clis], cls=Encoder)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sqlalchemy.ext.serializer` exists to support pickling (with `pickle` module) of queries, expressions and other *internal* SQLAlchemy objects, it doesn't deal with model objects. In no way it will help you to serialize model objects to XML. Probably something like [pyxser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyxser/) will be useful for you.